# powershell: separate and parse multiline string

Tags: powershell, parsing, split

I have been having trouble parsing an output from a rest api.
it is a Multiline string

```
Policy Name: Default_US_MultiSite Id: abc1234abc123 Buckets: support_us1_multisite,ch1ny2
Policy Name: Default_CH Id: 123456789acdef Buckets: question,answer,ch2,ch1,drive.me.closer
Policy Name: Default_NY Id: qrstuvwxyz9876 Buckets: demo,bucket1,test1,test,ny0,nyhello,goodbye,new.shoes,pizza,cutecats,theinternetisfor,Halloween,For-the-emperor
```

Now I do have an idea on how to split it by line, kinda and I try to use the following code

```
$data.Split("`n")
```

but I still cant figure out how to go about next and parse this

it doesnt recognize Policy Name, buckets, id as separate objects

do I convert it into or assign it as json or xml or something using more than just Convertto-xml or [xml] prefixing $data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
$data = @"
Policy Name: Default_US_MultiSite Id: abc1234abc123 Buckets: support_us1_multisite,ch1ny2
Policy Name: Default_CH Id: 123456789acdef Buckets: question,answer,ch2,ch1,drive.me.closer
Policy Name: Default_NY Id: qrstuvwxyz9876 Buckets: demo,bucket1,test1,test,ny0,nyhello,goodbye,new.shoes,pizza,cutecats,theinternetisfor,Halloween,For-the-emperor
"@

$data -split "`n" |
  Select-String 'Policy Name: (\w+) Id: (\w+) Buckets: (.+)' |
  ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property ([Ordered] @{
    "PolicyName" = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    "Id"         = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    "Buckets"    = $_.Matches[0].Groups[3].Value
  })
}
```

`Select-String` outputs `MatchInfo` objects. From these you can extract the match groups. `New-Object` outputs a new object based on the matches extracted from each output string.